# Distribute the points randomly within a polygon in QGIS

Tags: qgis-2

Say i have 20 points within a polygon. Each point represents a feature. out of which 15 were distributed and 5 points were one above the other in same location. Is there any way to randomly distribute those five points using QGIS?